# consistent resolution/scaling on many external displays

Tags: display

## TLDR

How can I set the text size on any externally connected monitor automatically?

## Details

My company moved to a new office with about 400 'freefloating' desks. Every morning, I arrive, find a free spot, connect my laptop, and start working. Each desk has an identical set-up, with a big monitor and a docking station.

Now, every time I sit down at a desk I haven't sat at before, I need to configure the monitor set-up, which for my mac means that I need to set the resolution to something acceptable as it always picks the largest text.

It's not a lot of work, but do it every single day for a few weeks and you too will want to automate it.

Is there a setting / third-party app / small script I could use to get these settings done?

Comment: There’s not enough information for me to make an answer, but I will note that [Automator has a “Watch me do” recording function](https://www.engadget.com/2009-01-19-mac-automation-creating-watch-me-do-workflows.html) that can automate a repetitive task and is [well documented here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E2%80%9CWatch+me+do%E2%80%9D) and by Apple. Is each display the same model and would the same settings work on all of them?

Comment: Yes. I'll give it a try, thank you. Also, let me know if /which more specific info you'd need